# jQuery - Detect scroll amount

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

On mobile devices, if there is a list of items and the user touches one, it is highlighted to indicate the user is touching it. However once the user begins to scroll (swipe up or down), the highlight disappears so the user knows they are not going to activate the button anymore when they release their finger.

I want to do something similar on a mobile, so I need to detect when the element is scrolled so I remove the highlight on the list item. However, the jquery `scroll` event seems to be fired at the same time as the `touchbegin`, not when the element is actually scrolled. So in order for this to work, I'll need to detect a few pixels of scrolling before removing the highlighting. What is the best way for me to achieve this?

Comment: It should be possible to manage the highlight class with jQuery and removing this class when scrolling thanks to .scroll()

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, but it seems scroll is being fired immediately after touchdown is fired so the highlight is removed immediatly

Comment: Oh sorry read to quick. Looks like - like you said - you have no choice but to detect if scrollTop has changed significantly in ordre to determine wether it's a click or a scroll... You might store the scrollTop on mouseDown event and compare it in *.scroll() function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, the `touchcancel` event works perfectly since it is fired when scrolling begins.